# System setting wont start.ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu

Title is saying whole problem. All system settings ( include network setting...so i cant connect to internet via WiFi ) won´t start and when i did:

`sudo unity-control-center`

it runs empty page for setting

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (in terminal):

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in terminal, you're gonna reset things up (worked for me):

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/
```